# How do I select the first image based on id and display in a (show) view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, there are user submitted reviews. Each review has many photos. What I need is to loop over the reviews that belong to a user and show the first photo in each review.

I appreciate your help :)

This works in console and I am able to return the correct photo. In review 1 there are 3 photos and this correctly returned the first one.

```
Photo.where(:review_id => 1).pluck(:file_name).first
```

Now I'm trying to display them in the users/show.html.erb file as such and it doesn't work.

```
<% @user.reviews.each do |review| %>
<%= image_tag review.firstphoto.url %>
<% end %>
```

I also tried defining a method to obtain the first photo in reviews_controller.rb

```
 def firstphoto
 @photo = Photo.where(:review_id => @review_id).pluck(:file_name).first
 end
```

Here are the associations

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :brand
belongs_to :user
has_many :photos

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :review

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :reviews
```

The photos are stored in S3 and use this schema to store in database.

```
create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.text     "file_name"
t.integer  "review_id"
```

To illustrate, the photos are correctly displayed in reviews/show.html.erb correctly with this code.

```
<% @review.photos.each do |photo| %>
<%= image_tag photo.file_name.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In users_controller.rb show action

```
@reviews = current_user.reviews
```

Then in users/show.html.erb file

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= image_tag review.first_photo %>
<% end %>
```

Now create a instance method in review.rb model be following code.

```
def first_photo
  photos.first.file_name.url if photos.first.present?
end
```

This will do what you want. Let me know If you are still facing this issue.

Comment: I don't have 'image' so I can't use photos.first.image.url.
I did try photos.first.file_name.url but it returns undefined method

Comment: Can you please let me know in which field you stored your image. So that I can help you out. If you are having problem to find the image field. Let me know the code where you are storing the image. I will find out by myself.

Comment: You want to show the image right? Or you just want to show the name?

Comment: I want to show the image. I have added schema details and a working example of the photos displayed correctly in a view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: undefined method `file_name' for nil:NilClass

This line is causing the error "photos.first.file_name.url"

Comment: this is because the photos not present for few of those reviews. Lets do one thing add  if photos.first.present? condition in your first_photo method as I did in my answer.

Comment: Solved. I had several reviews and one was lacking a photo. Thanks Pradeep!